# JQuery not working in JADE?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, pug

I was making a simple slideshow for my site and it seems that my JQuery doesn't get executed. Here's the code:

```
   div#slideshow

              img(src="/images/img1.png")

              img(src="/images/img2.png")

              img(src="/images/img3.png")

              img(src="/images/img4.png")

             script(type='text/javascript').
                $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
                setInterval(function() { 
                $('#slideshow > div:first')
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo('#slideshow');
                 },  3000);
```

*I'm running NodeJS with Express*

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `jQuery` before that `<script>`

`script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js")`

You may install it locally and change path according to.. and whatever version it depends upon you!

Comment: I'm a moron, completely forgot about including it.. Thanks mate :D